# If I have a minimum on a function f on $[a,b]$ at the point $x_1$ and I know $x_1$ is not $a$ or $b$, is $f'(x_1)=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Let $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ s.t $a<b$ and let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function that is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b]$. Suppose that there exists an $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$ and suppose that $f(x_0)<f(b)< f(a)$

Can I conclude that there exists a point $x_m\in[a,b]$ such that $f'(x_m)=0$?

By Weierstrass I know that there exists a minimum of $f$ on this neighborhood, thus as I know for certainty that neither $f(b)$ nor $f(a)$ are these minimal, can I conclude that the derivative of $f'(x_m)$ is $0$? I can't think of a scenario where the derivative of a minimum of $f$ is not $0$, except for at the edges of the neighborhood (which is not the case here).

Comment: Yes: you're restating a fact that any local minimum of a differentiable function (that's not an endpoint) is also a critical point. Those words can help you search for resources that give more details about why you're right.

Comment: If $x_m$ is a minimum, then for all other $x, f(x) - f(x_m) \ge 0$. This true both when $x - x_m > 0$ and when $x - x_m < 0$. So what does that say about the derivative?